# Anchor links going on top of the page behind sticky header. How to set smooth scroll JS to always keep a 75px top margin when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using a joomshaper template on my Joomla site. When I click on an anchor links to a section, it open the section on the top of the page behind the stick header. I tried the below but it doesn't work:

```
#aboutus:before {
    content: '';
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 75px; 
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```

I also tried setting a class to my link with the css below with no success:

```
a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I wonder if this can be achieved by modifying my current JS for smooth scroll to leave a top margin of 75px when scrolling. My JS are as follows:

```
<!-- SMOOTH SCROLL -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
<!-- End of SMOOTH SCROLL -->
```

Help plz.

Comment: There is no point in set `margin-top: -75px` for sticky positioning. Make a reproducible example here, pls.

Comment: To be clear, my header is 70px in height. When I click on my anchor link, instead of scrolling and making the section start on the top of the page behind the header, I want it to start under the header leaving at least 5px, thus 75px in total(70px header + 5px extra). I want to know if this is doable through the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but try something like

```
scrollTop: target.offset().top+70
```

The scroll top is stopping at the top of the page. You need to add onto the offset to move it down.

Full Code

```
<!-- SMOOTH SCROLL -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top+70
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
<!-- End of SMOOTH SCROLL -->
```

Comment: Genius!! scrollTop: target.offset().top-70 works perfect. +70 brings it more down.. Thanks